# Каково точное определение медианы отсортированного массива, элементами которого являются числа?

Tags: javascript

Массив, имеющий четное число элементов имеет медиану?

Comment: [Медиана (статистика)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Медиана_(статистика))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, неправильно.

Медиана набора чисел (массива) - такое число, что половина элементов из набора меньше его, а половина больше.

Если отсортировать массив A длиной n, то медианой при нечетном n будет `M = A[n/2]`

Медианным значением при чётном n обычно выступает среднее арифметическое двух средних по значению элементов `M = (A[(n-1)/2]+A[n/2])/2` .

Вообще в случае четной длины в качестве медианы может использоваться любое из чисел между средними (для 1,4,8,12 годные медианы 5,6,7) - для любого из этих чисел выполняется условие "сверху столько же чисел, сколько снизу"

Иногда берут одно из них - зависит это от соглашения ("нижняя" и "верхняя" медиана).

Comment: Спасибо. Ответ понятен. Т.е. медиана массива чисел - это среднее арифметическое его элементов, которое может не быть одним из его элементов?

Comment: нет. это неверно

Comment: Если в массиве нечётное количество элементов, то медиана - элемент в середине массива. Если четное, то мединана - среднее двух элементов  в середине массива.

Comment: @saverofPiter Нет же. Медиана может являться элементом массива. Про остальное уже написали.

Comment: Правильно. Может являться, а может и не являться.

Comment: Да, верно. Видимо, я прочитал как "не может быть. И про среднее арифметическое - нечёткая фраза.

Comment: Получается, что медиана любого массива целых чисел - это среднее арифметическое его элементов, округленное до целого значения.

Comment: Медиана - НЕ среднее арифметическое. Простой пример:  1,2,66. Медиана 2, ср.арифм.  - 23. Медиана не обязана быть целой (хотя иногда требуется)

Comment: Так вот я же и пытаюсь дать точное определение, что такое медиана.

Comment: А вы ответ прочитали?

Comment: Пример 1,2,66 отрицает все предыдущие определения.

Comment: Ответ читал. Все-таки в определении не может быть слов обычно.

Comment: Да как же отрицает? A[3//2]=A[1] = 2.

Comment: [Вот вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), в части "неуникальность" употреблено `На практике в этом случае чаще всего используют...`

Comment: Получается, что медиана массива целых чисел - это, если массив состоит из нечетного числа элементов, элемент с порядковым номером n/2, или это, если массив состоит из четного числа элементов, любое число, находящееся между элементом с порядковым номером n/2-1  и n/2. Так?

Comment: Да, так (имеется в виду позиция в отсортированном порядке)

Comment: Совершенно верно. Это про отсортированный массив.